# how to access a variable value outside for loop scope in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, for-loop, scope

I have run into a situation:

I have a Multidimensional array that prints out the path levels. I wanna print the path before

```
$maxlength = 4; // four levels

for($i = 0; $i<count($maxlength); $i++)
{
    $currentpath = $_GET['currentpath'];----->        /abc/def/g
    $path_level = explode('/',$currentpath);

    for($j = 0; $j<count($arr[$i]); $j++)
    {
         $temp = getcontentpath($arr[$i][$j]);
    }

    echo"<a href = '?path=$temp&action=abcd'>". $path_level[$i] ."</a>";
}
```

how can I access the value of temp outside the for loop scope?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score -1):

As I messed up this answer at first, let's try to clear this up. As mentioned in the comments below, and as mentioned in the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), PHP variables mostly only have a single  scope, thus the variable `$temp` in this question should be accessible also outside the for loop, even though it was declared inside the loop. Therefore the problem isn't the variable scope.

As Prashant found out him self, the problem was that the function was returning an empty value, thus the empty `$temp`

Comment: Thanks Christofer.. I got it.. it was because the function was returning empty value.. I was not getting I was looking for..

Comment: Say what? PHP does not have block level scope, `$temp` is accessible outside the loop either way!

Comment: Unlike C++/Java, PHP does not work the way you describe. The variable is not "private to the loop." Given his original code, $temp will be available anywhere after the line for which it is initialized and will be equal to whatever it was last set to within the loop or otherwise.

Comment: @deceze D'oh.. stupid me! Sorry about that, of course you're right. I've been working a lot with c# and javascript lately.

Comment: @JasonMcClellan You're right, that was a stupid answer. I've been working with c# and javascript lately, so I wasn't even reflecting on php's one level scope. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Prashant Glad you found the solution, even though my answer was wrong.

Comment: I don't know if it's still possible after the answer has been accepted, but you should remove or at least change your answer.